# Building a ASP.NET solution from command-line?

Tags: asp.net, command-line, build

How can I build an ASP.NET web application from the command line?

Answer (score 6):

Try this in a .bat file, replace v4.0.30319 with the appropriate version:

```
CD C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 
msbuild "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebSite.sln"
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [devenv.exe /Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b20w810z%28VS.80%29.aspx) switch, you give it a solution file to build, e.g.

```
devenv.exe "C:\Documents and Settings\someuser\MySolution.sln" /build DEBUG
```

If you have more complex build requirements then look into [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This is a round about way to do it, but you can use the [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) task as part of an [msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<ItemGroup>
  <Solutions Include="*.sln" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Build"   >
  <MSBuild BuildInParallel="true" Projects="@(Solutions)" RebaseOutputs="true"  />
</Target>
```

built with `msbuild`*`projectname`*`.proj` from the command line.

This may seem like overkill, but you can then add extra stuff into the project (like restarting websites, zipping files, Virtual machine control even!, code coverage) that can help you setup and test the project.

Answer (score 1):

As dumb as I might look, I have used "[aspnet_compiler.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28VS.80%29.aspx)" for compiling/deploying projects

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/2ca80dfd-b7d7-4e09-98ff-891b1570f4db

Answer (score 0):

To build a solution directly,

```
msbuild mysolution.sln
```

You'll find MSBuild in the Microsoft.NET folder in your Windows directory.

You may also want to pre-compile your Web site. Instructions for that are on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479044.aspx). If you use the Web Deployment project node (detailed at the bottom) then the deployment will happen automatically when you run `msbuild` on the solution file.