# How call .NET command prompt

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, build, asp.net

How to call .NET command prompt from Aspx to Build/Publish another windows application.

I have a windows application, that I want to build via my web application (aspx). How can I do that?

Comment: You've asked the same question, reworded, three times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886904/building-a-asp-net-solution-from-command-line

Comment: @Chris - that is building a web app, which is arguably different (see the answers)

Answer (score 2):

You want to build from aspx? Odd, but... Ultimately you have `Process.Start` which can execute any command, but you should think very carefully about which security context / identity your web-server is running as, and where it can read / write files, and the impact of using a web-server as a build-server.

Another option is to use the web-server to *queue* the work (perhaps MSMQ etc), and have a separate service (on a separate machine) dequeuing and doing the build / publish.

Comment: Or you could just download CruiseControl.NET or Hudson... Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the System.Diagnostics.Process object to spawn another task.  You probably don't want a command prompt.  Instead, you'll want to call MSBUILD.EXE directly and pass in a target of "Publish".

msbuild.exe /t:Publish MySolution.sln

Answer (score 0):

[This is how you execute a command](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3707996/NET-Tip-Execute-Commands-From-C.htm), and the command you want to execute is [MSBuild](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3707996/NET-Tip-Execute-Commands-From-C.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Write a .bat file that calls csc.exe or msbuild or whatever with the appropriate parameters. Execute the bat with System.Diagnostics.Process.Start method. You may need to set appropriate permissions for the web application process